# Styling Dynamically created TextBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using the MVVM pattern which is really new to me. I click **'Add Title'** and at the moment the textbox shows, and same happens when I click **'Add Question'**. The thing that is wrong is that they show up exactly below each other. When they click **'Add Title'** I want the text boxes to show with a margin from the left of **'20'** and then when I click **'Add Question'** I want the margin to show as **'40'**. They also need to have a space of **'20'** between all text boxes so there not directly underneath the textbox.

XAML CODE:

```
<Grid>

<Button Content="Add Question" Command="{Binding AddQuestionCommand}" Margin="615,19,179,724" />
    <Button Content="Add Title" Command="{Binding AddTitleCommand}" Margin="474,19,320,724" />

    <StackPanel>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Title}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding .}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Question}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding .}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </StackPanel>


</Grid>
```

I have tried to add the `Padding` property but it makes the text boxes bigger in height, and also I have tried the `Margin` but all text boxes are created dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

adjust margin according to your requirement

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Add Question" Command="{Binding AddQuestionCommand}" Margin="615,19,179,724" />
    <Button Content="Add Title" Command="{Binding AddTitleCommand}" Margin="474,19,320,724" />

    <StackPanel>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Title}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="20,20,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding .}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Question}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="40,20,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding .}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </StackPanel>


</Grid>
```

Comment: It says that my ItemsSource needs to be empty?

Comment: please check code again..i edited it.i have added extra itemscontrol mistakenly.

Comment: i dont know whats the problem there..you can change style for textbox also like this  <TextBox.Style>
                <Style  TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40,20,0,0"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>

Comment: `A style intended for type 'TextBox' cannot be applied to type 'ContentPresenter'.` This is what the error reads when i add the tragettype.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to define appearance structure is using the Grid control, specifying a row and a column.
Try something like this:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding Title}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding .}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

    <ItemsControl  Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Question}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding .}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```